# Does the Qt event listener occupy a file handle?

Tags: multithreading, qt, unix, signals

On a server running a Qt application I got the following error, as soon an other backup job starts running during the night:

```
QEventDispatcherUNIXPrivate(): Unable to create thread pipe: Too many open files
QEventDispatcherUNIXPrivate(): Can not continue without a thread pipe
```

Is it possible that the connect function needs a "unix file handle"? For example if I do the following, does it take an additional file handle resource from the OS, until I disconnect?

```
connect(this, SIGNAL(sendConfig(QString, QString)), deviceCon, SLOT(setDeviceConfig(QString, QString)));
emit sendConfig(configEntry, configValue);
disconnect(this, SIGNAL(sendConfig(QString, QString)), deviceCon, SLOT(setDeviceConfig(QString, QString)));
```

Thanks.
Spikey

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best I can find on the subject is this reference from [QT 4.2](http://cep.xor.aps.anl.gov/software/qt4-x11-4.2.2-browser/db/d00/class_q_event_dispatcher_u_n_i_x_private.html).

The answer to your question would be yes.  The Class opens a Pipe creating file handles which are then being used in `select` to process events.

**P.S.** Just confirmed similar method in 4.8

Comment: So, if I understand correctly: if I call connect() five times for a new thread (without a disconnect() call), every new thread will use up to 6 file handles (one for itself and one for every listening signal handle). Or even two file handles per connect()? Means 11 file handles?

Comment: No it doesn't you create a pipe for every dispatcher object.  So if you have one dispatcher with multiple connected threads the number of FDs would still be 2